# How to update all/several snapshot in WebStorm 2019 (jest)

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, webstorm

How I can update all/several snapshot in WebStorm?

I only have 1 button that updates snapshot, then I have to re-run tests and it’s not convenient.

[image: WebStorm update one snapshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [WEB-33822](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33822) to be notified on any progress with this feature